# How to store only upto 4 decimal places in a matlab variable?

Tags: matlab

I want a variable in matlab to store(not to be confused with display) only upto 4 decimal places.
Is there an inbuilt command for it?
I tried the following - but this gives an error:

```
a = [5.21365458 5.236985475 1.236598547 9.3265874];

k=1;
for i=1:length(a)
ast(k)=sprintf('%5.4f',a(i));
anum(k)=str2num(ast(k));
k=k+1;
end
```

error is :  ??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Comment: "I want a variable in matlab to store (not to be confused with display) only upto 4 decimal places". Is there a reason why you would intentionally want to loose precision when you can store the values in full precision and *display* them up to four decimal places? Even with rounding down to four decimal places, you are still storing the values in full precision.

Comment: I need only upto 4 decimal places to equate these values with a set of  other values and choose the one that matches till upto 4 decimal places. With the full precision, I can never match the two sets of numbers.

Comment: Then you should store the numbers with full precision, and write a function that tests for equality up to 4 decimal places. In fact, what you should have done is tell us what you *really* wanted to do (i.e. test for equality up to some level of precision) rather than what you thought you needed to do (i.e. mess around with how your data is stored).

Comment: I have two curves: C1 = f1(x1,y) and C2 = f2(x2,y) .i.e they share the same y values. I need to find for which 'y' value the 'x' values are closest to each other.

Comment: The condition $|a-b|<0.0001$ would check closeness of $a$ to $b$ within four decimal places. You don't need any rounding of values.

Comment: Thank you Kavka, it worked just as i wanted. And thanks to the others as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should round the numbers to four decimal places. This is easy to do in the workspace:

```
>> x = rand(1,4)
x =
   0.053378064308120   0.051670599653141   0.924623792776560   0.585692341974519
>> x = round(x*1e4) / 1e4
x =
   0.053400000000000   0.051700000000000   0.924600000000000   0.585700000000000
```

or you could write a function `roundToDP(x,numberOfDecimalPlaces)` that does it for you:

```
function x = roundToDP(x,n)
% "Round the matrix x to n decimal places"
x = round(x * 10^n) / 10^n;
```

now you can use that function in the workspace:

```
>> x = rand(1,4)
x =
   0.810201981892601   0.165116049955136   0.457688639337064   0.985975706057179
>> roundToDP(x,4)
ans =
   0.810200000000000   0.165100000000000   0.457700000000000   0.986000000000000
```

Comment: It did not entirely work out. Here's why:                                     a = [5.235689 2.124578 9.658754 21.235654];                    b=round(a*1e4)/1e4                                                  b = 5.235700000000000   2.124600000000000   9.658799999999999   21.235700000000001

Comment: That's a problem with floating point data, not with the rounding algorithm. It's impossible to store the value 9.6587 exactly as a floating point number, which is why it renders with a string of 9s on the end.

Comment: not very elegant, but I guess thats Matlab's fault for not including this as a prebuilt function...

Answer (score 0):

you could multiply the number by 10000 and store it as an integer then divide by 10000 before displaying

Answer (score 0):

You problem is related to the fact that anum becomes a char array. Use cell array instead:

> a = [5.21365458 5.236985475 1.236598547 9.3265874];
>
> anum = cell(size(a));
>   for i=1:numel(a)
>    anum{i} = str2num(sprintf('%5.4f',a(i)));
>   end

Also, as you can see, k variable is not needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fixed point object of matlab as mentioned in [Matlab reference to fixed point object](http://www.mathworks.in/help/toolbox/fixedpoint/ref/fi.html)