# matlab: keeping only first N digits of numbers

Tags: matlab, digits

I am trying to find a way in Matlab to truncate values of a vector, keeping only the first N digits (I don't want to round it, just to cut it.) of them. I wrote something which converts the values in strings, cut those and returns the number truncated, but it is too slow.

Any more clever solution?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please post what have you tried.

Comment: I tried everything suggested here.. but it didn't work

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600249/how-to-store-only-upto-4-decimal-places-in-a-matlab-variable/8601823#8601823

Comment: I am trying to merge two vectors which have numbers with a different resolution and to sort the resulting vector. This is what it doesn't work with the methods in the link.

If I do:

        v1_string = strtrim(cellstr(num2str(v1)));
        v2_string = strtrim(cellstr(num2str(v2)));

and then I loop 

        v1_new(i) = str2num(v1_string{i}(1:N));
        v2_new(i) = str2num(v2_string{i}(1:N));

this works, but it is too slow.

Answer (score 3):

Since you strictly say you do not want to round the number, here is one possible solution with the [`floor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html) function, where I just drop the numbers after the specified decimal numbers `N` I want to keep:

```
function trunc = truncate(x,N)
    trunc = floor(x*10^N)/10^N;
end
```

Here's a sample run:

```
>> b=rand(1,2)

b =

   0.957166948242946   0.485375648722841

>> truncate(b,3)

ans =

   0.957000000000000   0.485000000000000
```

---

Note that if you are considering numbers greater than one, the function above would have to be slightly modified:

```
function trunc = truncate(x,N)
        %For numbers equal or greater than 1, getting N first digits
        trunc=x;
        idx = x>=1;
        trunc(idx) = floor(x(idx)/10^N);

        %For decimals, keeping N first digits after comma
        trunc(~idx) = floor(x(~idx)*10^N)/10^N;
end
```

Another run of the `truncate` function:

```
>> b=[123 rand(1,2)]

b =

   1.0e+02 *

   1.230000000000000   0.004217612826263   0.009157355251891

>> truncate(b,2)

ans =

   1.000000000000000   0.420000000000000   0.910000000000000
```

It is important to note that no checks were made to verify if the input to the function has in fact an ammount of digits greater than N, which I assumed to be true.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. There is something probably related to the different resolution of the vectors which makes things weird. I haven't managed to figure it out what it is yet.

Comment: It would be better to use `fix` rather than `floor`, in case there are negative numbers

Comment: Was not aware of the fix function. Thanks for the tip. Do you mind if I aggregate to the answer?

Comment: @user1835630 Is it possible to get ahold of such an example where the results are *weird*?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same logic than in this example:

```
X =-1.665584378238097

Y = round(X / 0.01) * 0.01
```

> Y =
>
> -1.670000000000000

And apply it to vectors/matrices.